# NSMutableArray : Message sent to deallocated image

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am facing a strange problem concerning NSMutableArray. I searched several similar posts but with no luck.The situation is this : 
In my appDelegate I declare an   NSMutableArray property like this :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myRequests;
```

Then in a method of the same class I initialize the array like this :

```
self.myRequests = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Then in a for loop of the same method I add objects to the array:

```
while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    MyRequest *req = [MyRequest alloc];

    req.s_prp= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
   .
   .
   .
  [self.myRequests addObject:req];


  [req release];
}
```

I use this array to feed a uitableview with data.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 // Cell initialization ...

    MyRequest *req = (MyRequest *) [delegate.myRequests objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
    cell.stypeLabel.text = req.ser_type_name; // RANDOMLY OCCURING ERROR !!!!!!!!!!!
}
```

The exception occurs randomly and the message says : [MyRequest ser_type_name]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6e7af20

Is there anything wrong with the above code ?? MyRequest is a custom class. I am using a custom tableviewcell class.

MyRequest class is quite simple. It has several properties in the form

```
@property (retain,nonatomic)    NSString *ser_type_name;
```

and a dealloc method that releases the objects.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything which would be wrong... However I suggest you to properly implement/call/use [MyRequest init] method as well. Only doing an alloc may not have desired effects. (that's what init is for).

Comment: The error isn't in the code you've posted. It could be any place where you use `req` or `ser_type_name` - especially anywhere you release either of there.

Answer (score 2):

This line is incorrect:

```
MyRequest *req = [MyRequest alloc];
```

It should be:

```
MyRequest *req = [[MyRequest alloc] init];
```

There could be other errors, but that one is very glaring.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how MyRequest and its properties/ivars are defined, not are you showing how req.ser_type_name is set in your code. Depending on whether they are retained or not, you could be seeing some strange behavior because NSString's stringWithUTF8String returns an autoreleased string. You should check that and fix it if necessary (although I can't see how an error there would give you the message you are reporting)

Comment: Tim I updated my post. MyRequest class is quite simple. It only has some NSString properties which are retained, and a dealloc method.

Comment: Nothing else obvious comes to mind, so I would say it's time to check some non-obvious things. First, confirm  confirm that [myRequests count] is what you expect it to be, both after your while loop and before accessing its values in the cell initialization code. Second, confirm that your MyRequest's init method (if you have one) is returning itself rather than some other value that could be nil.